# how to write a function for array manipulation?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to **create a logical relationships without inbreeding** ...(animal crossing)

A   B   C   D   E

Each letter is below a family, which can **vary from 2 to N** (user input)

Array:

```
a   b    c  d    e  f
```

Step 1 (print: )

```
ab  bc  cd  de  ef  fa
```

Step 2 (print: )

```
abcd    bcde    cdef    defa    efab    fabc
```

end there, because for example if you try to cross the abcd everyone else has at least one letter

SOME RULES
- The elements cannot be repeated at any stage eg:  AA ou BB..CC..DD
- Elements of the groups may not be present in the next ... Example on the 3rd stage:

STRING:  *AB    BC  CD  DE  EA*

WRONG ->    AB BC

CORRECT -> AB CD

- First stage, just print each element of array
- Second Stage, print each element with the next, and the last with the first…
- Three stage, print the 4 elements each family…

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

In my database i have an array:

eg:
["Fish1","FishEx3","FishExample","FishSpecie","FishOtherSpecie"]

I need use this function for parse this.

Comment: the problem is I do not know how to start. I thought I'd create a counter that reads each element of the array and do the unions, but on the third step, becomes more complex, to check if the element is present in the next group.

Comment: putting something in a [*] will signify to everything that it will be handled as an array. see: http://htmldog.com/guides/javascript/beginner/arrays/

Comment: What will the input be for the function? Just a string seperated by spaces?

Comment: The array in database: ["Fish1","FishEx3","FishExample","FishSpecie","FishOtherSpecie"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a pretty solution but it works. [`PHP` Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/DtIeT)

```
function Crossbreed($species = array())
{
    if (empty($species)) {
        return array();
    }

    $half_way = array();
    $output = array();
    $species_length = count($species) - 1;

    foreach ($species as $index => $specie) {
        $next = $index + 1;
        if ($index >= $species_length) {
            $next = $index - $species_length;
        }
        $half_way[] = $specie . $species[$next];
    }

    foreach ($half_way as $index => $specie) {
        $next = $index + 2;
        if ($next >= $species_length + 1) {
            $next = $next - $species_length - 1;
        }
        $output[] = $specie . $half_way[$next];
    }

    return $output;
}

$species = array("Fish1","FishEx3","FishExample","FishSpecie","FishOtherSpecie");

$crossbred = Crossbreed($species);
```

Output of the `$half_way` variable (Did it with numbers in the array so its easy to read)

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 12 
    [1] => 23  
    [2] => 34  
    [3] => 45  
    [4] => 56  
    [5] => 67  
    [6] => 78  
    [7] => 89  
    [8] => 91 
)
```

Output of the function (Did it with numbers in the array so its easy to read)

```
Array (  
    [0] => 1234  
    [1] => 2345  
    [2] => 3456  
    [3] => 4567  
    [4] => 5678  
    [5] => 6789  
    [6] => 7891  
    [7] => 8912  
    [8] => 9123 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this functions:

```
$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

print_stage1($arr);
print_stage2($arr);
print_stage3($arr);

function increment($total, $pos, $inc){
    if($pos + $inc < $total)
        return $pos + $inc;
    else
        return ($pos + $inc) - $total;
}

function print_stage1($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key => $family){
        print $arr[$key]. " ";
    }
}

function print_stage2($arr){
    $total = count($arr);
    foreach($arr as $key => $family){
        $next_key = increment($total, $key, 1);
        print $arr[$key] . $arr[$next_key]. " ";
    }
}

function print_stage3($arr){
    $total = count($arr);
    foreach($arr as $key => $family){
        $next1 = increment($total, $key, 1);
        $next2 = increment($total, $key, 2);
        $next3 = increment($total, $key, 3);
        print $arr[$key] . $arr[$next1]. $arr[$next2]. $arr[$next3]. " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're explaining is a pretty simple unique combinatorics problem that can be solved with a stack. By shifting/popping one element at a time off the array/stack and concatenating it with another element you eventually exhaust your array. Repeat this as many times as you'd like for further combinatorics.

Here's an example.

```
function combine(Array $stack)
{
    $newStack = [];
    $lastElement = array_shift($stack);
    while($nextElement = array_shift($stack)) { // shift
        $newStack[] = $lastElement . $nextElement; // push
        $lastElement = $nextElement;
    }
    return $newStack;
}



var_dump($level1 = combine(['a','b','c','d','e','f']), $level2 = combine($level1));
```

Result is ...

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "ab"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "bc"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "cd"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "de"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "ef"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "abbc"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "bccd"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "cdde"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "deef"
}
```

Comment: Thx, Sherif for contribute, but the values couldnt repeat in  the strings. ((:

Comment: I'm a little confused about that since in your question you provide repeating values as the output and the answer you accepted also repeats values. Also, if you don't repeat you can only have 3 possible outcomes for the first set `['ab','cd','ef']` and one possible outcome for the second set `['abcd']`. Perhaps try clarifying the question with desired  output that pertains your actual constraints?

Comment: Notice the pattern in the array values, step 1 is just "index + 1" and step2 is "index + 2". Your ouput for the second array should be "index + 2", but it is "index + 1" atm.

Comment: Right, step 2 combines the combined values, which is what I *thought* was the requirement here. Clearly the question is just very poorly worded since they accepted your answer which fails one of the aforementioned requirements to not repeat sets. Obviously what the OP *really* wanted was a set and not successive combinatorics.